# UWP XAML Button with image and text in a Hub

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am learning different ways of achieving certain layouts with XAML in UWP (I know I'm late to the party but I just started with the UWP stuff!)

What I am trying to achieve is a main navigation page kind of thing from a hub control on my main page. At every HubSection, I will have button on each column of a 2-column grid, which will contain buttons. Ive'tried something similar [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411935/uwp-place-textblocks-on-image) but the debugger kept failing to attach to my UWP app when I used images instead of textblocks.

Essentially, what I've got until now is something like this: (I've shared my code down below)
[image]

But what I am trying to achieve is each button having its own image background and a separate TextBlock with semi-transparent background at the bottom centre of the button... (I've only photo shopped it, this is the thing I am trying to achieve...)

[image]

So this is what I've tried so far... I've also tried the relative panel but no luck...

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,10,10,0">
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Column 0 Item 1</TextBlock>
        <Image Source="/Assets/Artwork/150x150/RobCos_Worst_Nightmare_trophy.jpg" Stretch="None" />
    </Grid>
<StackPanel>

<TextBlock>Column 0 Item 1</TextBlock>
<Image Source="/Assets/Artwork/150x150/RobCos_Worst_Nightmare_trophy.jpg" Stretch="None" />
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

My complete code looks something like this for this page.

```
<Page
    x:Class="VaultManager.Terminal.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"    
    mc:Ignorable="d">


<Grid Background="Black">
    <Hub SectionHeaderClick="Hub_SectionHeaderClick">
        <Hub.Header>
            <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="My Hub Sample" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </Grid>
        </Hub.Header>
        <HubSection Header="Overview">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="150" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,10,10,0">
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock>Column 0 Item 1</TextBlock>
                                <Image Source="/Assets/Artwork/150x150/RobCos_Worst_Nightmare_trophy.jpg" Stretch="None" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <RelativePanel>
                                <TextBlock>Column 0 Item 2</TextBlock>
                                <Image Source="/Assets/Artwork/150x150/RobCos_Worst_Nightmare_trophy.jpg" Stretch="None" />
                            </RelativePanel>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock>Column 1 Item 1</TextBlock>
                                <Image Source="/Assets/Artwork/150x150/RobCos_Worst_Nightmare_trophy.jpg" Stretch="None" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock>Column 1 Item 2</TextBlock>
                                <Image Source="/Assets/Artwork/150x150/RobCos_Worst_Nightmare_trophy.jpg" Stretch="None" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection Header="Videos" Name="Videos">
        <!-- yada yada -->
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection Header="Audios" Name="Audios">
        <!-- blah blah -->
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good job giving us all that info. You may want to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530068/how-do-i-place-a-text-over-a-image-in-a-button-in-winrt) since the asker in that question seems to have had a similar issue. The answerer suggested using a Grid instead of a StackPanel. Hope that helps. After that, you should be able to adjust the transparency of the text. If you are using visual studio you can just click on the text element and adjust the background brush from the Properties tab. The button w/ the image should look like this:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text = "Column 0 Item 1">
                                    <TextBlock.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="(**Colour here**)"  Opacity = "(**Opacity Here {1 being opaque and 0 being transparent}**)/>
                                    </TextBlock.Background></TextBlock>
                                <Image Source="/Assets/Artwork/150x150/RobCos_Worst_Nightmare_trophy.jpg" Stretch="None" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Button>
```

Comment: Funny enough, wrapping that bit of code with a Grid actually solved the problem. I still don't understand why but thanks :)

Comment: It works with a Grid because, unless specified, each element within a Grid defaults to placement in row 0, column 0. So in this case the TextBlock and Image are both in row 0, column 0 which creates an overlay effect.